# Update Elm record with multiple constructors

Tags: elm

Is there a way to modify field for a type with multiple constructors?

```
type U = S | C { xxx : String }

This is not a record, so it has no fields to update!

5|   let c = C { xxx = "DD"} in case c of C {} -> { c | xxx = "ZZ" } 
                                                    ^
This `c` value is a:

    U

But I need a record!
```

Answer (score 1):

In `type U = S | C { xxx : String }`, `xxx` is not a field of `U`. It is a field of the record contained in `C`. Those are separate types that can be deconstructed into separate values. And the way to do that is to use `case` to match the `C` constructor and bind the contained value to a name (or further deconstruct it) so we can refer to it on the right side of the `->`.

But then you also need to handle the possibility of `c` being `S`. What should be returned then? Maybe a default? Or maybe you actually want to return a `U`? I've assumed the former here, but the latter would just be construction values of `U` as you would anywhere else.

```
let
    c =
        C { xxx = "DD" }
in
case c of
    C record ->
        { record | xxx = "ZZ" }

    S ->
        -- What to do here?
        { xxx = "default?" }
```

Comment: I understand the Elm complain, I need a workaround. TypeScript and Kotlin can benefit from if condition to narrow the type. Haskell has pattern alias feature.